# Line chart from external csv-file

Tags: json, csv, d3.js, highcharts, visualization

I want to make a line chart that automatically updates with data from this page: http://www2.nve.no/h/hd/plotreal/Q/0027.00025.000/knekkpunkt.csv

The .csv is updated once per hour, and contains date and two values for amount of water flowing in a river. How can I set up a Highcharts, or similar, to get data from this file, and render to a graph?

I don't have server access to nve.no, where the data is stored.

Appreciate any ideas!

Answer (score 2):

As a part of the ZingChart team, we've received several questions similar to this one. You're likely to initially run in to cross-domain issues when using a resource that is hosted on another domain, especially since you do not have any access to that server.

There are ways around this, however. One method involves using JSONP and YQL (Yahoo! Query Language). Using [YQL](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/), you can pull from the URL that you've provided and have the data returned as JSONP.

Here is a JSbin demo that shows this off: http://jsbin.com/hidel/1/edit?html,output

Comment: That's looking promising. As you say, I don't have access to the server, and after a bit of research I came to the conclusion that JSONP would be something to look into.

In your demo, are the data stored in any way, so it will be accessible for Highcharts?

Comment: In that demo, no, the data is not stored in any way, it's simply alerted. However, in the success function, you can set the value of a js variable to the returned data string in order to store it. After that, you'll have to parse the string of data into the format used by Highcharts.

Answer (score 0):

At the beginning I recommend you to visit the [working with data](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/preprocessing) article.